# SQL - Recursive conditions in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not the best in SQL so sorry if I'm asking stupid questions :)

Let's have a table like this:

```
|id|  name  |  nickname  |
|==|========|============|
| 1|      Jo|      Banana|
| 2|Margaret|The Princess|
| 3|   Perry|  The Monkey|
| 4|Margaret|   The Queen|
| 5|        |     The Rat|
| 6|        |     The Cat|
```

where `nickname` is always unique.

And I'm trying to get results like this:

```
|id|  name  |  nickname  |     display_name      |
|==|========|============|=======================|
| 1|      Jo|      Banana|                     Jo|
| 2|Margaret|The Princess|Margaret (The Princess)
| 3|   Perry|  The Monkey|                  Perry|
| 4|Margaret|   The Queen|   Margaret (The Queen)|
| 5|        |     The Rat|                The Rat|
| 6|        |     The Cat|                The Cat|
```

Basically the logic is:

1. If `name` is **empty** then `display_name = 'nickname'`
2. If `name` is **unique** then `display_name = 'name'`
3. If `name` is **not_unique** then `display_name = 'name (nickname)'`

Can I achieve it with one SQL query only? If so - how? If not - what are the alternatives?

Currently I do it with my programing language but I have to send for each row of the result another SQL query to check if there are other records with the same name which is OK for filtered results but is too greedy when retrieving the whole table (4 000 rows and growing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the window function version of `COUNT()` to determine whether the `name` for a given row is unique without performing a subquery.  For example:

```
SELECT
  id, name, nickname,
  CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(name, '') = '' THEN nickname
    WHEN (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)) = 1 THEN name
    ELSE name + ' (' + nickname + ')'
  END AS display_name
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Hi @john-bollinger , many thanks for your answer. Two questions that just pop into my mind: 1) The `OVER (PARTITION BY )` command is only for `sqlserver`? 2) Why the `row_number` would not work? Thanks

Comment: @AndyK, the `OVER()` clause is what makes `COUNT()` a window function instead of an aggregate function.  These are standard SQL features since SQL2003, extended in SQL2008.  Many SQL databases other than SQL Server implement them (Oracle and PostgreSQL being but two of many), but not all do (MySQL being one of the more prominant exceptions).

Comment: @AndyK, the `ROW_NUMBER()` function returns the ordinal number of the current row relative to the partitioning and/or order defined by the `OVER()` clause.  That allows you to recognize the second and subsequent rows of any partition as belonging to a partition with more than one row, but when the row number is `1` you don't know whether there are any subsequent rows in that row's partition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for your explanations in the comments. I learned from you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
SELECT
    *
    ,display_name =
                    CASE
                        WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) = 1) THEN name
                        WHEN ISNULL(name, '') = '' THEN nickname
                        ELSE name + ' (' + nickname + ')'
                    END
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: A window function is a good way to go, but `ROW_NUMBER()` is the wrong one for this job.  This particular use will produce the wrong result for the lowest-`id` row in each group with the same `name` value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: You are right... I have Modified my  answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: +1 for your fast reply. However I choose John's answer because his example works perfect while yours doesn't work properly for the first row (but all the others 3999 rows are OK so thank you very much ;)